# resize SQL Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, resize

Is there a way to resize a local varchar in sql?

like:

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS VARCHAR(3)
REDIM @MYVARIABLE(50)
```

That will change the size of @MYVARIABLE to 50 char.

Note: I need to keep the variable because I use it after.
So I cant use another one.

Sample 2:

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS VARCHAR(4)
SET @MYVARIABLE = 'TEST'
SET @MYVARIABLE = '12345'
SELECT @MYVARIABLE
```

here, MYVARIABLE = '1234' at the end. should be '12345'
how to do it (and keep myvariable)

can I delete the current and create a new one?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Why would you want to do this, I could understand it for a column, but a variable is easy to change from the beginning. Just set it to the maximum that you know you will need, or if it could get very big and you have no idea what size that could be then just use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Comment: alex, Its for a little patch who do little change of variable. but the variable can be bigger after. the variable came from a program who push the var as the exact size of his content. I try to not change every thing, just the size of the varchar.

Comment: can I delete it and recreate a new one with the same name but different definition?

Comment: tank you, I will take another way to do what I want.

Comment: I've re-edited my comments into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Set you variable to the largest size you know you will need in the first place e.g.:

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS NVARCHAR(50)
```

Or if you don't know how big you need then you could always use MAX:

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

If the length of the variable is important to you then you can get that after it is assigned a value:

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LENGTHOFMYVARIABLE AS INT
SET @MYVARIABLE = 'somerandomtext'
SET @LENGTHOFMYVARIABLE = LEN(@MYVARIABLE)
```

In this case `@LENGTHOFMYVARIABLE` would be 14.

**UPDATE**

The only other way I know of how to do this is to use a secondary temp variable:

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS NVARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @MYBIGGERTEMPVARIABLE AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @MYBIGGERTEMPVARIABLE = @MYVARIABLE
```

Obviously there are some limitations if the variable gets passed along again, but apart from that the only other way would be to change the source variable length to be a more reasonable value. Really there isn't much of a reason to have variables of such a small size.

Comment: its a program who create the variable and his size. I dont have any control of that.

Comment: I dont need to know the length. I want to put in the var, something bigger than the size of the var.

Answer (score 0):

you can use temp variable :

```
DECLARE @MYVARIABLE AS VARCHAR(3)

DECLARE @myVal as VARCHAR(50)=@MYVARIABLE
```

Comment: I will need to change every place my var was used. I try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot alter the definition of a variable, nor undeclare a variable. It's definition is fixed, from the point it is declared, until the end of the batch.

It's definition even takes effect if the declaration doesn't appear to run:

```
if 1 = 0
begin
    declare @a varchar(3)
    print 'declared!'
end
else
begin
    print 'not declared?'
end
set @a = 'abc'
print @a
```

prints:

```
not declared?
abc
```

Since you can't change the way that the variable is being declared, you'll have to give up on this attempted approach to your overall problem (but I can't offer suggestions, since you've not described your overall problem)